# Эффект JS/FLASH

Tags: анимация, flash, эффекты, javascript

Добрый день! Не знаю, по теме ли вопрос, но:
ищу эффект свертывания/подгинания уголка у изображения.
Т.е. имеется изображение, необходимо при наведении свернуть его (как папирус к примеру) или отогнуть уголок - за отогнутой частью появится текст.

Надеюсь, понятно объяснил. Всем спасибо.

Comment: да, уже нашел, его и взял. Спасибо.
Но если кто найдет эффект сворачивания в сверток - буду признателен.
Добавь отдельным постом а не комментарием чтоб мог выбрать ответ.

Comment: Если работаете только с изображением, то вам поможет canvas и математика.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то наподобие такого? [Turn.js](http://turnjs.com/#getting-started)

Comment: а есть информация о том как отогнуть уголок не перелистывая?

Comment: нет, никогда с этим плагином тесно не работал

Comment: жаль, перелистывание сделал без проблем. а вот как отогнуть только.. 
Мб есть какой другой плагин? И как этот эффект вообще называется, а то нагуглить сложно.

Comment: я гуглил по запросу `jQuery paper effect`